# Pass data from promise to worker threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, promise, node-worker-threads

Hi i have a problem passing data from promise to worker threads.

i want to pass the "data" to worker threads and from worker threads to main thread.

I receive this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined.

Here's my code below:

```
const { isMainThread, parentPort, Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { join } = require("path");

const workLoad = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const firstArg = process.argv[2];
      const secondArg =
        process.argv[3] ?? Math.random().toString(36).substring(8) + ".txt";

      const encodedSha256 = crypto
        .createHash("sha256")
        .update(firstArg)
        .digest("hex");
      const base64 = Buffer.from(secondArg).toString("base64");

      const encodeData = `${encodedSha256}\n${base64}`;

      fs.writeFileSync(join(firstArg, secondArg), encodeData, {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      });
      const data = fs.readFileSync(join(firstArg, secondArg), {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      });
      resolve(data);
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};

if (isMainThread) {
  const worker = new Worker(__filename);
  worker.on("message", (message) => console.log(message));
} else {
  workLoad().then((res) => parentPort.postMessage(res));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for the async code? Wrapping a Promise() with an async function is an antipattern. So you can remove the `return new Promise() {...` bit. Second, there is nothing asynchronous in the function, so no need for the async treatment in the first place.  Finally, pretty sure you should be using `worker.postMessage(res)` to send to the sub-process.

Comment: Noted i will remove the async from promise, where i can put the `worker.postMessage(res)`? @RandyCasburn

Comment: replace `parentPort.postMessage()` with `worker.postMessage()`

Comment: You don't need the promise either.

Comment: can i call worker? in worker thread even if i declare it inside the main thread?

Comment: My mistake - I misunderstood this: "_pass the "data" to worker threads and from worker threads to main thread_" - I guess the "_to worker threads_" threw me off.